# Как организовать хранение ссылок в базе MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, сервер, хостинг

Есть страница авторизации, на которой пользователь вводит свой логин и пароль, дальше ему становятся видны доступные ссылки. Сами ссылки со страницами хранятся на сервере. Страница с авторизацией и база данных с логинами и паролями хранится на хостинге. Каким образом хранить ссылки на сайты в базе данных, если например для одного пользователя их может быть несколько?

Comment: В отдельной таблице, отдельными строками, ID-пользователя, ссылка

Comment: Так пользователь же будет видеть эти ссылки при переходе по ней? Т.е. если он просто скопирует, то спокойно попадет на эту страницу без авторизации.

Comment: А вы в вопросе разве это упомянули ? как по вопросу догадаться, что вы решили скрыть ссылки от пользователей ? Ну тогда в БД у записи пользователь-ссылка есть некий ID, давать человеку ссылку на свой сайт на некую страницу которая возьмет ID и потом перенаправит. Правда тут как ни крути человек всегда может видеть куда он в итоге перешел

Comment: Я что-то сразу не написал, а после вашего ответа вспомнил. Спасибо, вроде понятно. Возможен такой вариант, что если даже пользователь будет иметь прямую ссылку, он просто автоматически будет перебрасываться на страницу авторизации?

Comment: Если страница на которую указывает ссылка на вашем сайте, то конечно вы можете редиректить на авторзацию если пользователь пришел без куки открытой на него сессии

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: А если страница на которую указывает ссылка лежит на сервере, ее как-то можно скрыть?

Answer (score 1):

Как это называется, проблема молотка и микроскопа?
Вам нужно сделать нормальную авторизацию пользователя, после которой он будет иметь доступ туда, куда не имеют доступ  гости, по средством сессии, а не мудрить не понятно что со скрытием от него его же URL.